# Joel Test "ticks" disappear when printing SO careers advert

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The green "ticks" on Stack Overflow Careers job adverts that indicate the passing of one of the elements of the Joel Test do not appear when printing out the job advert.

This job (an example that includes Joel Test ratings): http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/90975/senior-software-engineers-itunes-store-big-data-apple

Shows just fine in the browser:

[image]

However, when attempting to print (or print preview) the advert, the green "ticks" disappear:

[image]

Note that this appears to affect all major browsers (Chrome, IE and Firefox) and makes it difficult to know what a given companies Joel Test score is when reviewing a job advert from only a printed copy.

It would be nice if the CSS could be fixed to allow the green ticks to be printed.

Comment: There's probably an option to print images. Try turning it on.

Comment: Thanks for the report. Will get up a fix soon.

Comment: @Undo, you are correct and that would work. However, the images in question are substantive (convey information, not just aesthetics) so shouldn't be handled as background images. By handling them properly, visitors can rely on default printing behavior.

Comment: Should be fixed now. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah,  didn't know how that worked. Learned something today!